# Enum value `Browsable(false)`

Tags: c#, enums

is there a way to make an enum value not browsable to combo box
or just, not to come back from `Enum.GetValues()` ??

```
public enum DomainTypes  
{  
    [Browsable(true)]  
     Client = 1,  
    [Browsable(false)]  
    SecretClient = 2,    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create a Wrapper to obtain the values you want to display?

Comment: @Luis : you should have had answered the question with question. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing already in place to do this for you with the `Enum.GetValues()` method. If you want to use attributes, you can create your own custom attribute and use it via reflection:

```
public class BrowsableAttribute : Attribute
{
  public bool IsBrowsable { get; protected set; }
  public BrowsableAttribute(bool isBrowsable)
  {
    this.IsBrowsable = isBrowsable;
  }
}

public enum DomainTypes  
{  
    [Browsable(true)]  
     Client = 1,  
    [Browsable(false)]  
    SecretClient = 2,    
}
```

And then you can use reflection to check for custom attributes and generate a list of Enums based on the `Browsable` attribute.

Answer (score 5):

This is a generic method (based on another SO answer which I can't find) which you can call on any enum.
By the way, the Browsable attribute is already defined in System.ComponentModel.
For example:

```
ComboBox.DataSource = EnumList.Of<DomainTypes>();

...

public class EnumList
{
    public static List<T> Of<T>()
    {
        return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
            .Cast<T>()
            .Where(x => 
                {
                    BrowsableAttribute attribute = typeof(T)
                        .GetField(Enum.GetName(typeof(T), x))
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(BrowsableAttribute),false)
                        .FirstOrDefault() as BrowsableAttribute;
                    return attribute == null || attribute.Browsable == true;
                }
            )
        .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It really can't be done in C# - a public enumeration exposes all members.  Instead, consider using a wrapper class to hide/expose the items selectively.  Maybe something like this:

```
public sealed class EnumWrapper
{
    private int _value;
    private string _name;

    private EnumWrapper(int value, string name)
    {
        _value = value;
        _name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _name;
    }

    // Allow visibility to only the items you want to
    public static EnumWrapper Client = new EnumWrapper(0, "Client");
    public static EnumWrapper AnotherClient= new EnumWrapper(1, "AnotherClient");

    // The internal keyword makes it only visible internally
    internal static readonly EnumWrapper SecretClient= new EnumWrapper(-1, "SecretClient");
}
```

Hope this helps.  Good luck!